# how to join two columns of the table with two columns of other table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns ***SKU_new*** and **order_ID** on #temp table  that match with **SKU** and **ID** column of orders table i am using *inner join* but it keeps executing and does not show any result.

my query is

```
SELECT t.SKU_new, t.ID_Order
INTO #caseone
FROM dbo.Order_No AS n JOIN
     dbo.Orders AS o
     ON n.Order_No = o.Order_No JOIN
     #Temp AS t
     ON (t.ID_Order = o.ID or t.SKU_new = o.SKU);
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: its keeps executing and not showing result. i am using ssms

Comment: Please clarify if "does not show any result" means 1)This sql should show a result immediately or 2)The table defined by #caseone should have data in it to display.  With 3 answers already, none have addressed this.  Perhaps you need to remove "Into #caseone"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios where Query keep on executing

One is when there is uncommitted Transactions on Tables
Then try like

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
        SELECT t.SKU_new, t.ID_Order
        INTO #caseone
        FROM dbo.Order_No AS n JOIN
       dbo.Orders AS o
       ON n.Order_No = o.Order_No JOIN
       #Temp AS t
       ON (t.ID_Order = o.ID or t.SKU_new = o.SKU)
```

If it scenario 2, it might have so many records with bad indexing. To check whether it is getting records or not try Top in the select

```
        SELECT Top 1  t.SKU_new, t.ID_Order
        INTO #caseone
        FROM dbo.Order_No AS n JOIN
       dbo.Orders AS o
       ON n.Order_No = o.Order_No JOIN
       #Temp AS t
       ON (t.ID_Order = o.ID or t.SKU_new = o.SKU
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading your question you say " 2 columns SKU_new **and** order_ID "

Based on that wouldn't you use an AND instead of an OR in your Join?

```
SELECT  t.SKU_new
,       t.ID_Order
INTO    #caseone
FROM    dbo.Order_No AS n
        JOIN dbo.Orders AS o ON n.Order_No = o.Order_No
        JOIN #Temp AS t ON t.ID_Order = o.ID
                           AND t.SKU_new = o.SKU;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
SELECT t.SKU_new
, t.ID_Order
INTO #caseone
FROM #temp t 
JOIN dbo.orders o 
    ON t.ID_Order = o.ID 
    AND t.SKU_new = o.SKU
JOIN dbo.Order_No n 
    ON n.Order_No = o.Order_No
```